# Magento 2 Set Order not working

Tags: product-collection, magento-2.2.5, price-sorting

I'm trying to set Custom Sort Order in Collection using `afterSetCollection()`

Following is my code
di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="sortby_extend_default_sort_filters" type="Package\Module\Plugin\Toolbar" sortOrder="99" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Following is my `Toolbar.php`

```
    public function afterSetCollection($collection, \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $result)
        {
            $collection = $result->getCollection();
            $currentOrder = $result->getCurrentOrder();
            $currentDirection = $result->getCurrentDirection();
            if ($currentOrder && $currentOrder == 'price') {
                $result->getCollection()->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr('new_price ' . $currentDirection));
                //Following is also not working
                $result->getCollection()->setOrder('new_price',$currentDirection);
            }
            return $result;
        }
```

When I try to print select query in `list.phtml` I get sorting only for follwoing

```
 `e`.`entity_id` DESC
```

Can anyone suggest, Why my sorting not applied?

FYI : `new_price` is created on the fly which working properly in `aroundSetCollection()` but not working for `afterSetCollection()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that in another(in `afterSetCollection()`) file following code was given

```
$collection->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
```

Due this it was not working.

Removing above line has solved issue for me.